# Docker desktop cannot start after Win 11 updates

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently, I've updated my Windows 11 OS. It seems that this caused problems to Docker desktop installation.

Error states:

> An unexpected error occurred
>
> Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to :
>
> Some WSL system related access rights are not set correctly. This sometimes happens after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory. Please try to reboot the computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop.

I've found similar screenshot with same error message:
[image]

I have tried to restart the computer, uninstall/install Docker desktop, disable/enable Windows features, related to containerization. All in vain. What else I can try to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution on a [GitHub dialog](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13104), which worked for me.
It boils down to following commands in PowerShell:

```
wsl --update
wsl --shutdown
```